# Changing map scale in ArcMap after almost finished digitizing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, scale, digitizing

I'm just about to design a map that represents different areas in my immediate living environment. I Unfortunately made a big mistake at the beginning of my project. The current scale is given by ArcMap with 1:30,000. 1: 3,000 would be the correct scale.

Is it possible to transform the already almost finalized digitization in any way to the correct scale, so that the distances as well as the areas in my map correspond to the reality?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking for, because polygons have no inherent "scale."  *Scale* refers to the size at which a feature is *rendered* (compared to the size of what it represents). Thus, normally, one changes the scale of a map simply by zooming in or out.  Could you please edit your question to help us better understand what you need to do?

Comment: Maybe your real question is: "How can I change map scale in ArcMap, after I'm almost finished digitizing?" If that's right, please edit the title. Then anyone knowing arcmap can help. (I could be off the mark.)

Comment: Yes, of course. Martin, you are totally right.

Comment: Why can't you zoom in and out using the mouse scroll wheel?

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the [scale tool in ArcMAP](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t0000008m000000.htm)

See also this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34768/is-it-possible-to-increase-reduce-features-proportionally), that seems to be similar.

Comment: That would maybe be a solution, if I had an opportunity to scale my polygons to a specific scale.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually want to divide the coordinates of your features' vertices by 1000? You could do this by accessing the shape field of the features with an UpdateCursor and divide the X and Y properties of each features's point. You can find a code example for polylines in [this post](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/96195-change-z-coordinates-of-vertexes-by-updatecursor). 
You should update the shapeFieldName variable to match your feature class and replace `pntOut = arcpy.Point(pnt.X, pnt.Y, 9999)` with `pntOut = arcpy.Point(pnt.X/1000, pnt.Y/1000)`. For polygons, replace `Polyline` with `Polygon` and for points, simplify the code by removing the array.

Comment: No, that's not, what I want to do.

Comment: I believe GISGe may have meant "multiply by 10" instead of "divide by 1000," but the distinction is of little importance because the solution is essentially the same. So if this is not what you want to do, jan, then please explain more clearly what it is you *do* want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get something from nothing.  You can attempt to *conflate* between existing datasets at different scales, and you can *generalize* 1:3k data to 1:30k scale, but
there is no process which will make 1:30k data into 1:3k.  You will need to obtain (and digitize, if non-digital) appropriate scale source maps.

Comment: It's not about to get more details. The details remain the same. It's all about the distances. The basis was an aerial image with a scale of 1:3,000, which was read by mistake as 1:30,000. That's why I want to get it back to 1:3,000.